# Spring and maven class library and accessing xml file

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have 2 `Maven` projects. One of them is using `Spring`, other one is a class library that has an `xml` file and a class file that uses this `xml` file. In the `Spring` project, I call the class then I got an error:

```
"I am not found the xml file"
```

This xml file is unimportant for the Spring project. Because it's in the class library project, I don't want to access the `xml` file directly, I just want to call the classes and the classes access the `xml` file.

Why did this happen? And what is the solution?

*Tomcat: 9*

*IDE: Eclipse*

***Note: There is no problem when any classes in class library wants to access the xml file***

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I copy the xml file to spring project as same folder name in maven repository. It worked but I don't understand why am I must to do that :)

Answer (score 1):

for that, you have to configure as Java based project.otherwise, it will load the XML file first.